# forecast package from R - Can a time series model saved to predict later

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Can we use forecast package to create a time series model and save  it for later prediction. i am using the forecast method with 'ets' or 'arima' as one of the parameters.But it predicts the point estimate,but we can not save the model which can generate future prediction with the same model.

Comment: Why can't you save the model? How did you try? Did you try `?saveRDS`

Comment: Try reading the help files for either ets or Arima.

Comment: Hello Professor - I am trying to use   forecast(ts.data.stl, method="arima",h=1440) , and this is forecasting the value for next 1440 slots. I am able to save it and load the  predicted data (1440 slots) at latter point of time. But i am getting the saved data only. What i am trying to achieve is to save the model and load it at a latter point of time to predict. And i may choose a different h value at that point of time.  Appreciate your help in this regards .. Thanks Snehashis